# Does Mathematica 6 on Mac OS X 10.6.2 work for you?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, mathematica

I don't have the latest version of Mathematica, but Wolfram [claims this shouldn't be a problem](http://support.wolfram.com/technotes/snowleopard.html). However, when I launch Mma, it immediately terminates; crash reporter yields a little info:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _gluNewTess
  Referenced from: /Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/Mathematica
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
```

Can anyone confirm if this is my problem only or if it is an endemic problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the full version number?  I can confirm that 6.0.1 works fine for me on 10.6.2.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation that it's my machine that's broken; I'm also using 6.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem on my machine only. Long story short, redownloading the Mac OS X 10.6.2 combo updater and re-installing fixed the problem.

(As it happens, after asking this question I discovered other apps crashing for the same or similar reasons.)

After upgrading to Mac OS X 10.6.1 (or 10.6.2, not sure), I was getting the following message printed many times whenever (most) terminal commands were executed:

```
dyld: shared cached file was build against a different libSystem.dylib, ignoring cache
```

[*sic*]. The known solution for this problem, `sudo update_dyld_shared_cache` plus reboot, did not fix the problem. And then this Mathematica crashing indicated the problem was a little more serious. Luckily the re-application of the system updater did the trick.

Who know what caused the problem originally; I tend to run a fairly clean system.